# Can't login to http://en.zbiornik.com/

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Folks, I am able to successfully run Tor Browser and access for example Gmail.
However, I cannot login to http://en.zbiornik.com/ - it always says "invalid password".
I have added the following line to:

```
TrackHostExits zbiornik.com
some dir\Tor Browser\Data\Tor\torrc
```

but it did not help
What else shall I try?

Comment: Have you tried several times, using a new identity each time? If so, that site may be blocking Tor exit nodes. Try through a proxy. As a simple test, search for zbiornik using https://www.ixquick.com/do/search, and use the ixquick proxy.

Comment: Do you have a account there? Did you create your account via Tor or some other way? Did you allow script on? Have you tried to connect via VPN? Does it work with VPN?

Comment: I do have an account. I've created it before I started using Tor.<br>Here is link to my screeshot: ![Screenshot](http://kociofrance.tumblr.com/image/90160239848) <br>does that mean that scripts are enabled or disabled?

Comment: Folks, I was able to use proxy to log-in to the site. Here is [the list of proxies](http://www.publicproxyservers.com/proxy/list1.html). Please note that some of them cut-out JS, pictures and many other things rendering the site unusable, but some let you configure options to make it work. Not sure if Tor exit nodes were blocked or what, but proxy helps. Actually I am fairly interested to investigate more, why zbiornik did not work. Any suggestions for better diagnostics?